# produce character vector for each column containing the rowname if the value is > 0

Tags: r, select, vector, filter, tidyverse

I'm looking to create a unique character vector in R for each column in my df (so my df has 20 cols so I'd get 20 vectors). I want each vector to report the character value for the rowname which had a value greater than zero.

```
> dput(ex.df)
structure(list(NASQAN2015.147.348 = c(0L, 87L, 0L, 105L, 0L), 
    NASQAN2015.148.348 = c(0L, 57L, 0L, 23L, 21L), NASQAN2015.161.348 = c(17L, 
    77L, 0L, 146L, 0L)), row.names = c("ee866b92e722c35819b112aadc4ac885", 
"afc0eeec83a181be740331928d883362", "294c12d6881a2ed67aa1557cda9889ff", 
"466c2c4cb06ba39543c40a74c027008a", "fd0b270adb11f2781450c2e057e50f07"
), class = "data.frame")
```

In ex.df I'd expect three character vectors that'd look like:

`NASQAN2015.147.348 ch [1:2] "afc0eeec83a181be740331928d883362" "466c2c4cb06ba39543c40a74c027008a"`

`NASQAN2015.148.348 ch [1:3] "afc0eeec83a181be740331928d883362" "466c2c4cb06ba39543c40a74c027008a" "fd0b270adb11f2781450c2e057e50f07"`

`NASQAN2015.161.348 ch [1:3] "ee866b92e722c35819b112aadc4ac885" "afc0eeec83a181be740331928d883362" "466c2c4cb06ba39543c40a74c027008a"`

I know to select for one column I could run something like:

```
ex.df %>% filter(NASQAN2015.147.348 > 0)
```

but that applies to all columns and outputs a df (if I save the object).

Answer (score 1):

## base R

```r
lapply(ex.df, function(z) rownames(ex.df)[z > 0])
# $NASQAN2015.147.348
# [1] "afc0eeec83a181be740331928d883362" "466c2c4cb06ba39543c40a74c027008a"
# $NASQAN2015.148.348
# [1] "afc0eeec83a181be740331928d883362" "466c2c4cb06ba39543c40a74c027008a" "fd0b270adb11f2781450c2e057e50f07"
# $NASQAN2015.161.348
# [1] "ee866b92e722c35819b112aadc4ac885" "afc0eeec83a181be740331928d883362" "466c2c4cb06ba39543c40a74c027008a"
```

## tidyverse

literal translation of `lapply` to `map`:

```r
purrr::map(ex.df, function(z) rownames(ex.df)[z > 0])
```

(though this is likely over-complicated)

```r
ex.df |>
  tibble::rownames_to_column() |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -rowname) |>
  filter(value > 0) |>
  summarize(rowname = list(unique(rowname)), .by = name) |>
  with(setNames(rowname, name))
# $NASQAN2015.161.348
# [1] "ee866b92e722c35819b112aadc4ac885" "afc0eeec83a181be740331928d883362" "466c2c4cb06ba39543c40a74c027008a"
# $NASQAN2015.147.348
# [1] "afc0eeec83a181be740331928d883362" "466c2c4cb06ba39543c40a74c027008a"
# $NASQAN2015.148.348
# [1] "afc0eeec83a181be740331928d883362" "466c2c4cb06ba39543c40a74c027008a" "fd0b270adb11f2781450c2e057e50f07"
```